# Select box with jquery Auto suggestion

Tags: jquery, html

I want a select box where a user can select the options manually by clicking and as well in the same way he could able to type in that select box(Auto suggestion).

Thanks in advance,
Sowmya.

Comment: Try jqueryui autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Yes i have tried that.When we are typing then only it is displaying the options. In case of clicking on the arrow no action is performing there.

Comment: Read the options for that page: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: (Although the `chosen` plugin suggested by Niels looks a lot nicer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. You mean jQueryUI Autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
```

B. Or do you mean a Tag input http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/
C. what you want in your comment: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: No you just go through this link http://udoo.in .There you will find a select box with the functionality what i mean.

Comment: Look here: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Yup..!! its too good. Thnku